# URL Rewriting not working - rewrite rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have enabled the rewrite module in apache .
Later i developed the .htaccess file in root .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test.html $ test.php
```

but its not working ?
Internal server error occurs.
What to do next?

Comment: Perhaps you want to give us some more information.

Comment: Yea. You gonna have to be *a bit* more specific about your problem. The only anwser I can give you now is "42". Just find the question.

Comment: This is not a question.  Should be closed, or updated with more information.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say mod_rewrite is not turned on, or it's not allowed in an `.htaccess` file. Check the error log.

Your rule is also wrong, it should be

```
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.php
```

The dot means "any character" and should be escaped; you also had a space after `html`.